# Canonical bundle and skyscraper sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves, derived-categories, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $Y$ be a smooth projective variety, $\omega_Y$ its canonical bundle and $k(y)$ the skyscraper sheaf. In a proof in Huybrechts' book, he uses the "restriction" map $r_{y_1,y_2} \colon \omega_Y^k \to \omega_Y^k(y_1) \oplus \omega_Y^k(y_2) \simeq k(y_1) \oplus k(y_2)$, where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are distinct closed points.

I don't understand how the map is defined and why the isomorphism $\omega_Y^k(y_1) \oplus \omega_Y^k(y_2) \simeq k(y_1) \oplus k(y_2)$ holds.

Comment: Perhaps $\omega^k_Y(y)$ means some kind of 'skyscraper' of $\omega_Y^k$ at $y$ (I guess one way that could be interpreted is by taking $\omega_k^Y \otimes \mathcal{O}_y$), which should then be the same as $k(y)$ because $\omega_Y$ is locally free of rank $1$.

Comment: What's going on with the superscript $k$ on $\omega_Y$?

Comment: @KReiser the $k$-tensor power... This is the proof of Bondal-Orlov theorem. Huybrechts is demonstrating that $\omega_Y$ is ample, showing that the $k$-tensor power is very ample

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer so the author "didn't write" the tensor product...(?)

Comment: So I guess $k \neq k$...

Comment: To expand on my flippant comment, earlier comments are pointing to the fact that $k$ is being used to denote both the ground field (in the notation $k(y)$) and an integer (in the notation $\omega_Y^k$). It might be a good idea to change one of them for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

For any affine scheme $X:=Spec(A)$ and any $A$-module $E$ there is a canonical map

$$ \rho_E(x): E \rightarrow E\otimes_A \kappa(x)$$

defined by $\rho_E(x)(e):= e\otimes 1$, where $1\in \kappa(x)$ is the multiplicative identity. Here $\kappa(x)$ is the residue field of the point $x$: If you let $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$ be the prime ideal corresponding to $x$ you define $\kappa(x):=A_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}$. It follows $\rho_E(x)$ is a map of $A$-modules, hence you get an induced map of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules

$$\rho_{\mathcal{E},x}: \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}(x).$$

If $E:=A$ you get a map

$$\rho_{\mathcal{O}_X,x}: \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \underline{\kappa(x)}.$$

The sheaf $\underline{\kappa(x)}$ is the sky-scraper sheaf of the point $x$ (this is defined in Hartshornes book).

If $x,y \in X$ are two points there is a canonical map

$$\rho_{\mathcal{O}_X,(x,y)}: \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \underline{\kappa(x)\oplus \kappa(y)}$$

defined using the canonical map

$$ \rho_A(x,y): A \rightarrow \kappa(x)\oplus \kappa(y),$$

where $\rho_A(x,y)(a):=(\rho(x)(a), \rho(y)(a))\in \kappa(x)\oplus \kappa(y).$

Example. If $Y$ is a smooth complex affine algebraic variety of dimension $n$ and $x\in Y$ a (closed) point, it follows the map

$$\rho_{\mathcal{O}_Y,x}: \mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow \underline{\kappa(x)}$$

evlauates a global section at the point $x$. If $Y:=Spec(A)$ where $A$ is a finitely generated algebra over the complex numbers, and $f\in A$ is a global section of the structure sheaf, it follows the canonical map

$$\rho_{A,x}: A \rightarrow \kappa(x)$$

is the evaluation: If $x\in Y \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ where $x:=(x_1,..,x_n)$
it follows $\rho_{A,x}(f):=f(x_1,..,x_n)$ is the value of the function $f$ at $x$. In algebraic geometry you sometimes meet non-closed points, hence the point $x$ may correspond to a non-maximal prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A$, and then the "value" of $f$ at $x$ becomes more un-intuitive. It is an element in the residue field  $\kappa(x)$ of $x$, and this field is a transcendental extension of the base field.

When the base field $k$ is non-algebraically closed and $Y$ is a scheme of finite type over $k$ it follows from the HNSS the residue field $\kappa(x)$ at a closed point is a finite extension of the base field $k$. The value $s(x)$ of a global section lives in the residue field $\kappa(x)$ and this field changes with the point. If $k$ is the ring of integers and $x,y$ are two closed points in $Y$
it follows the residue fields $\kappa(x)$ and $\kappa(y)$ may have different characteristic.

If $Y$ is smooth and we define the canonical bundle as follows: $\omega_Y:=\wedge^n \Omega^1_Y$ (see Hartshorne, page 180), and since the rank of the cotangent bundle is $n$, it follows $\omega_Y$ is an invertible sheaf on $Y$. Hence it is locally trivial of rank one, hence you get something similar: There is a map

$$I0,\text{   } \rho_{\omega, x}: \omega_Y \rightarrow \underline{\kappa(x)}$$

Question: "I don't understand how the map is defined and why the isomorphism $ω_Y(y_1)\oplus ω_Y(y_2)\cong k(y_1)\oplus k(y_2)$ holds".

Answer: Since the rank of $\omega_Y$ is one, it follows the fiber $\omega_Y(x)$ is isomorphic to $\kappa(x)$ - the fiber is one-dimensional, hence there is in the case when $Y$ is smooth an isomorphism

$$ \omega_Y(x) \oplus \omega_Y(y) \cong \kappa(x) \oplus \kappa(y).$$

If $\omega^k_Y:=\omega^{\otimes k}_Y$ is the $k$'th tensor product of $\omega_Y$ with itself it follows $\omega^k_Y$ is still an invertible sheaf, and you get a similarly defined isomorphism

$$I1. \text{   } \omega^k_Y(x) \oplus \omega^k_Y(y) \cong \kappa(x)\oplus \kappa(y).$$

Note: The isomorphisms in $I0$ and $I1$ depend on the choice of a local trivialization of $\omega^k_Y$ around the points $x,y$.

Example. If $k:=\mathbb{R}$ is the real numbers and $A:=\mathbb{k}[x]$ is the ring of polynomials with real coefficients you may classify all maximal ideals. A maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ in $A$ on the following form: If the residue field is the field of real numbers $k$ it follows $\mathfrak{m}_1=(x-r)$ with $r\in k$ a real number. If the residue field is the field $K:=\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers, it follows $\mathfrak{m}_2$ is on the form
$\mathfrak{m}_2=(p_z(x))$ where $z:=a+ib \in K-k$ is a non real complex number
and

$$p_z(x):=(x-z)(x-\overline{z})=x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2.$$

In the case $1$ you get an evaluation map

$$\rho_1: A \rightarrow \kappa(\mathfrak{m_1})$$

defined by $\rho_1(f(x)):=f(r)$. In the case $2$ you get an evaluation map

$$\rho_2: A \rightarrow \kappa(\mathfrak{m}_2)$$

and if you want an explicit complex number you must choose an isomorphism $i:\kappa(\mathfrak{m}_2)\cong \mathbb{C}$. Here you have two choices: $i(x):=z$ or $i(x):=\overline{z}$. Once you have made a choice you get $\rho_2(f(x)):=f(i(x))\in \mathbb{C}$. Hence for a point that is not rational over $k$ your "value" and "evaluation map" depends on the choice of an isomorphism $i$. I believe this is written out in detail in Hartshornes book "Algebraic geometry".

When doing algebraic geometry you are seldom interested in the "value" of a function $f(x)$ or a section $s(x)$ in the fiber. What you are studying is where the function (or section) is zero, and this does not depend on the choice of an isomorphism $i$. Hence the fact that you have to choose an isomorphism $i$ above does not create problems.

Some people argue that to introduce non-maximal prime ideals is "less intuitive", but as you can observe above: If you work over a non-algebraically closed field, the elements in the structure sheaf do not give rise to functions in the classical sense.