# If $(X, \mathcal O_X)$ is a scheme, what is $\mathcal O_X(U)$ where $U$ is any open subset (not necessarily affine open)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, definition, schemes

If $(X, \mathcal O_X)$ is a scheme, what is $\mathcal O_X(U)$ where $U$ is any open subset (not necessarily affine open)?

Below is what I currently know.

---

Let $A$ be a ring.

Hartshorne defines the structure sheaf on $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ as:

> For an open subset $U \subset \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, we define $\mathcal O(U)$ to be the set of functions $s: U \to \coprod_{\mathfrak p \in U} A_{\mathfrak p}$, such that:
> i.) $s(\mathfrak p) \in A_{\mathfrak p}$
> ii.) for each $\mathfrak{p} \in U$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $\mathfrak p$, contained in $U$, and elements $a, f \in A$ such that for each $\mathfrak q \in V$, we have $f \notin \mathfrak q$ and $s(\mathfrak q) = a/f \in A_{\mathfrak q}$.

---

---

Vakil first defines a sheaf of rings on the distinguished base $D(f) \subset \operatorname{Spec}(A)$:

> Define $\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec} A}(D(f))$ to be the localization of $A$ at the multiplicative $\{g \in A \mid D(f) \subset D(g)\}$.

An exercise shows that $\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec} A}(D(f)) \cong A_f$, and that the stalk of at a point $\mathfrak p$ is $A_\mathfrak p$.

Since we have a sheaf on a base, we can extend this to all open $U \subset \operatorname{Spec} A$

> Define $\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec} A}(U)$ to be the set of all $(s_{\mathfrak p})_{\mathfrak p \in U} \in \prod_{\mathfrak p \in U} A_\mathfrak p$ such that 
> i.) $s_\mathfrak p \in A_{\mathfrak p}$
> ii.) for each $\mathfrak{p} \in U$, there is a neighborhood $D(f)$ of $\mathfrak p$, contained in $U$, and an element $a \in A$ such that for each $\mathfrak q \in D(f)$, we have $s_\mathfrak q = a/f^n \in A_{\mathfrak q}$.

---

---

I can see how the two definitions are related: given a function $s \in \mathcal O(U)$ as in Hartshorne, we get $(s(\mathfrak p))_{\mathfrak p \in U} \in \prod_{\mathfrak p \in U} A_\mathfrak p$ as in Vakil. The converse is similar.

Both authors define:

> A scheme $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ is a ringed space such that any point of $X$ has an open neighborhood $U$ such that $(U, \mathcal O_X|_U)$ is isomorphic to an affine scheme.

I am confused about functions on a scheme $(X,\mathcal O_X)$.

It seems Hartshorne is explicitly defining what functions on an affine scheme should be in his definition, but not what functions on an arbitrary scheme should be. Why?

Vakil writes: Functions on an open subset $U$ of a locally ringed space have values at each point of $U$. The value at $p\in X$ of such a function lies in $\mathcal O_{X,p}/ \mathfrak m_p$ where $\mathfrak m_p$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_{X,p}$.

Comment: It is sufficient to define the structure sheaf on a topological basis. As long as you can define what $\mathcal{O}_X(.)$ is doing on a topological basis then you extend it to an arbitrary open set by using a projective limit

Comment: More explicitly, given an arbitrary open subset $U$, we can cover it by affine opens $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ and cover the intersections $U_i\cap U_j$ by affine opens $\{U_{ijk}\}_{k\in K_{ij}}$; the sheaf condition then gives that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is the equalizer of $\prod_{i\in I}\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)\rightrightarrows\prod_{i,j\in I, k\in K_{ij}} \mathcal{O}_X(U_{ijk})$.

Comment: Since Vakil writes that the value of $p \in X$ lies in $\mathcal O_{X,p}/\mathfrak m_p$, is it wrong to say a function on an open subset $U$ is a function $U \to \coprod_{p \in U} \mathcal O_{X,p}/\mathfrak m_p$?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "is". It's certainly correct that an element of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ gives a function $U\to \coprod_{p\in U} \kappa(p)$, but it's not true that such a function uniquely specifies an element of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$. It might not specify an element of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ (there are compatibility conditions) and it might not do so uniquely (if $X$ is nonreduced, for instance).

Comment: @KReiser I see. How about if we impose some conditions like i and ii above? The reason I'm considering this is because in general if $\mathscr F$ is a sheaf on a space $X$, then for any open $U\subset  X$, the natural map $\mathscr F (U)\hookrightarrow \prod_{x \in U} \mathscr F_x$ is injective.

Comment: Maybe I should have written $U \to \prod_{p \in U} \mathcal O_{X,p}/\mathfrak m_p$ in my first comment above?

Comment: For sheaves, it is true that the natural map $\mathcal{F}(U)\to\prod_{x\in U} \mathcal{F}_x$ is injective, but that's not what you've asked about - you're asking about $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \prod_{x\in U} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/m_x$, not $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \prod_{x\in U} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Consider $\operatorname{Spec} k[e]/(e^2)$, for instance - the first option gives $k[e]/(e^2)\to k$ by modding out $e$, while the second gives $k[e]/(e^2)\to k[e]/(e^2)$ by the identity.

Comment: @KReiser Ok. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing. Just trying to understand what exactly is $\mathcal O_X(U)$ in the case $U$ is not affine, and what it means to be a function on $U$. I thought it would have an easy explicit description that I was missing.

Comment: I don't think it's super important to know what $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is most of the time. It's enough to know a couple strategies for calculating it when you need to - the equalizer diagram above and the intersection of stalks in an integral scheme are probably the most applicable tools. As for what a function on $U$ is, I find it helpful to think that it's a morphism from $U$ to $\Bbb A^1$, just like functions on manifolds are morphisms to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @KReiser That actually makes sense since $\kappa(x)$ is a field. So, we can interpret a function on $U$ as a morphism from $U$ to $\mathbb A^1_{\kappa(x)}$.

Comment: @KReiser How come a function on $U \subset \operatorname{Spec} A$ is defined as a function which takes $\mathfrak p \in U$ to an element in $A_\mathfrak p$ and not to an element in $A_p/\mathfrak{p} A_\mathfrak p$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120895/discussion-between-kreiser-and-user46372819).

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** I am confused about functions on a scheme $(X,O_X)$. It seems Hartshorne is explicitly defining what functions on an affine scheme should be in his definition, but not what functions on an arbitrary scheme should be. Why?"

**Answer:** There are many discussions on this site and the MO site on the structure sheaf of a scheme and the relation with "sheaves of functions", real algebraic varieties etc. You find some information here:

[Regular rational functions over real projective lines and projective spaces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3989123/regular-rational-functions-over-real-projective-lines-and-projective-spaces/3990167#3990167)

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377922/building-algebraic-geometry-without-prime-ideals/378961#378961

**Question:** "Vakil writes: Functions on an open subset $U$ of a locally ringed space have values at each point of $U$. The value at $p∈X$ of such a function lies in $O_{X,p}/m_p$ where $m_p$ is the maximal ideal of $O_{X,p}$."

**Answer:** Locally if $U:=Spec(A)$, a section $s\in \mathcal{O}_U(U)\cong A$ is an element in the ring $A$, and given any prime ideal $\mathfrak{m}\in A$ you get a canonical "evaluation map"

$$ev: A \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}A_{\mathfrak{m}} :=\kappa(\mathfrak{m})$$

and $ev(s)$ is the "value" of the section $s$  at the point $\mathfrak{m}$. This is "unintuitive" since the residue field $\kappa(\mathfrak{m})$ changes with the prime ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, hence $s$ is not a function in the classical sense. There is however a way to construct for any Hilbert-Jacobson ring (scheme) $A$ a ringed topological space $Max(A)$ where you only considers maximal ideals in $A$. Such spaces are "more intuitive". One of the reasons for the introduction of prime ideals for "schemes" is to include nilpotent elements in geometry, and with the above construction of $Max(A)$ you get a locally ringed space with nilpotent elements in the structure sheaf. In the above links you find a discussion of this.

**Example:** Here:

[Canonical bundle and skyscraper sheaf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4002990/canonical-bundle-and-skyscraper-sheaf/4003057#4003057)

I give an example to illustrate that a section $s$ of the structure sheaf of $S:=Spec(\mathbb{R}[x])$ does not give a function in the classical sense. This is because the (non-generic) points in $S$ have residue field $k:=\mathbb{R}$ or $K:=\mathbb{C}$. When a point has residue field $k$ you get a well defined function $s:S(k) \rightarrow k$. When the residue field is $K$ you have to make a choice. In the case of $S$ it is possible to make such a consistent choice.

For a real differentiable manifold $M$ and an open subset $U\subseteq M$ if you let $\mathcal{O}(U)$ be the set of differentiable real valued functions $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ you get a sheaf of functions $\mathcal{O}$ on $M$ and the pair $(M, \mathcal{O})$ is a locally ringed space. In Hartshorne
he defines for any commutative unital ring $A$ a locally ringed space $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ where $X:=Spec(A)$ is the set of prime ideals in $A$ with the Zariski topology. A section $s \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is not a function in the classical sense: There is no field $K$ with the property that you may interpret the ring $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ as a "set of maps" $s: U \rightarrow K$ with multiplication and addition induced from the one on $K$.

Comment: I'm not quite up to projective schemes yet. It seems there is not a canonical answer to what are functions on $U$ except that they take a point $x \in U$ to $\mathcal O_{X,x}/\mathfrak m_x$?

Comment: I still don't quite see why Hartshorne explicitly defines what functions on an affine scheme should be, but not what functions on an arbitrary scheme should be.